# I am getting weird symbols in my response instead of actual text

Tags: java, android, web-services, response

I have `SoapBuilder` class in android that calls out to a webservice.  Now I have used it in a previous application and it worked great.  The problem with this new application is that instead of me getting the actual response back, I am getting what looks like some sort of wing ding symbols.  My webservice is a .net webservice like my other application.  The only difference that I can see is that I was using a ssl on my previous app and now I'm not.  So I changed all of my socket stuff ssl to reg sockets and socketfactorys.  Here is my code I get the weird symbols when I am reading the in (bufferedreader) `StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder(contentLength);`

```
if (contentLength > 0) {
    int readBytes = 0;
    int c = -1;
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        contentBuilder.append((char) c);
        readBytes++;
    }
}
```

Here is my entire code for `SoapBuilder`.

```
public class SoapBuilder {
    private final String TAG = "SOAPBUILDER";
    String Server = SQBApplication.SOAP_SERVER;
    String WebServicePath = SQBApplication.SOAP_WEBSERVICEPATH;
    String SoapAction = "";
    String MethodName = "";
    String XmlNamespace = SQBApplication.SOAP_XMLNAMESPACE;
    Integer Port = SQBApplication.SOAP_PORT;
    Integer BufferSize = 2048;
    // boolean IsSSL = true;
    private ArrayList<String> ParamNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> ParamData = new ArrayList<String>();

    public SoapBuilder(String soapMethod) {
        MethodName = soapMethod;
        SoapAction = XmlNamespace + MethodName;
    }

    public SoapBuilder(String server, String soapMethod)
    {
        MethodName = soapMethod;
        SoapAction = XmlNamespace + MethodName;
        Server = server;
    }

    public SoapBuilder(String server, String webServicePath, String namespace, String soapMethod)
    {
        MethodName = soapMethod;
        XmlNamespace = namespace;
        SoapAction = XmlNamespace + MethodName;
        Server = server;
        WebServicePath = webServicePath;
    }

    public void AddParameter(String Name, String Data) {
        ParamNames.add(Name);
        ParamData.add(Data);
    }

    public String sendRequest() throws Exception {
        String retval = "";
        String message = "";

        StringBuilder postAction = new StringBuilder();
        // send an HTTP request to the web service
        postAction.append("POST " + WebServicePath + " HTTP/1.1\n");
        postAction.append("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\n");
        postAction.append("SOAPAction: \"" + SoapAction + "\"\n");
        postAction.append("Host: " + Server + ":" + Port + "\n");
        postAction.append("Content-Length: %s\n");
        postAction.append("Expect: 100-continue\n");
        postAction.append("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\n");
        postAction.append("Connection: Close\n");
        postAction.append("\n");
        ArrayList<String> envelope = new ArrayList<String>();
        envelope.add("<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">");
        envelope.add("<s:Body xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">");
        envelope.add("<" + MethodName + " xmlns=\"" + XmlNamespace + "\">");
        // Parameters passed to the method are added here
        for (int t = 0; t < ParamNames.size(); t++) {
            String name = (String) ParamNames.get(t);
            String data = (String) ParamData.get(t);
            envelope.add("<" + name + ">" + data + "</" + name + ">");
        }
        envelope.add("</" + MethodName + ">");
        envelope.add("</s:Body>");
        envelope.add("</s:Envelope>");

        int si = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < envelope.size(); i++) {
            si += envelope.get(i).length();
        }

        StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder(si);
        for (int i = 0; i < envelope.size(); i++) {
            bodyBuilder.append(envelope.get(i));
        }
        message = String.format(postAction.toString(),
        Integer.toString(bodyBuilder.length()));
        message += bodyBuilder.toString();
        Socket socket = null;
        boolean autoflush = true;
        try {
            SocketFactory socketFactory = (SocketFactory) SocketFactory
                .getDefault();
            socket = (Socket) socketFactory.createSocket(Server, Port);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),
            autoflush);

            System.out.println("request length: " + message.length());
            if(message.length() > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            {
                throw new IOException("message length exceeds max size");
            }
            socket.setSendBufferSize(message.length());
            //only except if the message wouldn't have succeeded anyway
            if(socket.getSendBufferSize() < message.length() && socket.getSendBufferSize() != message.length())
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            out.print(message);
            out.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"), BufferSize);
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        int ci;

        Pattern httpPattern = Pattern.compile(
            "HTTP/1.\\d\\s+(\\d+)\\s+[\\w\\s]+\\r\\n",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Pattern contentLengthPattern = Pattern.compile(
            "Content-Length\\:\\s*(\\d+)\\r\\n",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        int contentLength = -1;
        String httpResponse = "";
        while ((ci = in.read()) != -1) {
            response.append((char) ci);
            Matcher lengthMatcher = contentLengthPattern.matcher(response
                .toString());
            Matcher httpMatcher = httpPattern.matcher(response.toString());

            if (lengthMatcher.find()) {
                contentLength = Integer.parseInt(lengthMatcher.group(1));
            }
            if (httpMatcher.find()) {
                httpResponse = httpMatcher.group(1);
            }

            if (contentLength > 0) {
                // contentLength+=2;
                break;
            }
        }

        StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder(contentLength);
        if (contentLength > 0) {
            int readBytes = 0;
            int c = -1;
            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                contentBuilder.append((char) c);
                readBytes++;
            }

        }

        System.out.println(httpResponse);
        if (httpResponse.equals("200")) {

            Pattern responsePattern = Pattern.compile(
                "<soap:Envelope.*?>(.+)</soap:Envelope>",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL
                | Pattern.MULTILINE);

            Pattern responseNullPattern = Pattern.compile("<" + MethodName
                + "Response.+?/>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE
                | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
            Matcher responseMatcher = responsePattern
                .matcher(contentBuilder);
            Matcher responseNullMatcher = responseNullPattern
                .matcher(contentBuilder);
            System.out.println(contentBuilder);
            if (responseMatcher.find()) {
                retval = responseMatcher.group(0);// responseMatcher.group(0);
            } else if (responseNullMatcher.find()) {
                retval = null;
            }
        } else if (httpResponse.equals("500")) {
            Pattern faultPattern = Pattern.compile(
                "<soap.Fault.+?>(.+)</soap.Fault>",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL
                | Pattern.MULTILINE);
            Matcher faultMatcher = faultPattern.matcher(contentBuilder);
            faultMatcher.find();
            retval = faultMatcher.group(0);
        } else {
            throw new Exception(String.format(
                "HTTP response not recognized: %s", httpResponse));
        }

        in.close();
        socket.close();
        return retval;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show actual, incorrect data (hex, not characters) being returned along with expected.

Comment: �
�
�Thats what a lot of them look like.  Mainly wingdings

Comment: A hex-dump, not characters, please.

Comment: how do you do a hex dump in java?

Answer (score 0):

I can pretty much guarantee that this is down to an encoding problem.  Wycats wrote an excellent post on this which you should read (ignore the Ruby specificity):

http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/

Comment: OK, my webservice definition expects the request to be UTF-8, and as you can see above, my soapbuilder uses UTF-8 so they are both the same.

Comment: Regardless, that doesn't mean that every link in the chain is also using UTF-8

Comment: ok so why would it work fine with my last webservice, and not with this one.  What other parts of the chain should I check based on the above soapbuilder?

Comment: Ok, so I just tested my soapbuilder with my other webservice and it works great.  I had to change the socket stuff to sslsockets but it worked great, so im guessing its in my webservere?  Even though when I look at my WSDL it shows that it returns in utd-8.  Please any specific detailed help would be great, because the article was not much help.  Thanks

Comment: Is there anyone that can help me with this situation based off of my above soapbuilder?